# How to auto generate multiple auto values using keyProperty and keyColumn?

Tags: java, h2, mybatis

I am using **H2** database and I am trying to auto generate multiple values using `keyProperty` and `keyColumn` on my insert statement using **mybatis**.

**Insert statement:**

```
<insert id="insertWeighmentHder" 
    parameterType="WMHeader" flushCache="true" statementType="PREPARED" 
    keyProperty="headerid,weighslipno" keyColumn="headerid,weighslipno"
    useGeneratedKeys="true" timeout="20000">
```

When I call the insert statement my application crashes with this exception:

> SEVERE: Exception Handler. Unable to process further. EXIT.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.apconic.ws.ui.open.weighment.WeighmentComposite.printTicket(WeighmentComposite.java:464)
>     at
>   com.apconic.ws.ui.open.weighment.WeighmentComposite.handleSaveClick(WeighmentComposite.java:322)
>     at
>   com.apconic.ws.ui.weighment.AbstractWeighmentCaptureComposite.handleSaveClick(AbstractWeighmentCaptureComposite.java:105)
>     at
>   com.apconic.ws.ui.weighment.AbstractWeighmentCaptureComposite$1.widgetSelected(AbstractWeighmentCaptureComposite.java:117)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.apconic.ws.ui.open.dialogs.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:152)

What am I doing wrong?

How can I auto-generate multiple values using `keyProperty` and `keyColumn` in **mybatis** paired with **H2**?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes my application get crashed after this query is called, and getting headerid as null but my record is inserted but get crashed when I am going to see it through application

Comment: Nemit you should add information about the errors you are getting to the question, if you get an exception add it. Also are you saying the record gets inserted but the id is null?

Comment: @Dzyann thanks 'I have added exception which I am getting'

Comment: Maybe you could list the source code of `com.apconic.ws.ui.open.weighment.WeighmentComposite.printTicket(WeighmentComposite.java:464)`? Because there you get a NPE.